# How to restrict combination of element values in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to write an XML Schema where the following XML documents are allowed:

```
<e><e1>1</e1><e2>2</e2></e>
<e><e1>2</e1><e2>1</e2></e>
```

but not:

```
<e><e1>1</e1><e2>1</e2></e>
<e><e1>2</e1><e2>2</e2></e>
```

Each line represents a single document.

For this I created a schema with a complex type `etype` like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="etype">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="e1">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
            <xs:enumeration value="1"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="2"></xs:enumeration>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="e2">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
            <xs:enumeration value="1"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="2"></xs:enumeration>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Now I tried to declare an element which restricts `etype`:

```
  <xs:element name="e">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="etype">
        ...
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

But I'm at a loss on how to exactly formulate the restriction.

Basically I need something like ***e2 is allowed a given set of values, and this set of values depends on the value of e1***. The example above is simplified.

Is this possible with XML Schema? If yes, how?

Comment: XSD 1.0 cannot express *e2 is allowed a given set of values,
and this set of values depends on the value of e1*, but XSD 1.1 could via an assertion.  Is XSD 1.1 an option for you?

Comment: @kjhughes libxml needs to be able to valid the schema, therefore XSD 1.1 isn't an option AFAIK.

Comment: Right.  Then you'll have to check that constraint outside of XSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XSD 1.0

Constraining the values of elements based upon other elements is not possible in XSD 1.0.

### XSD 1.1

XSD 1.1 has assertions (and even conditional type assignment) that allow constraints to vary per values per document.  If XSD 1.1 isn't an option (as it is not for libxml), then such checks have to be performed outside of XSD.